# x64 OSX Assembly MOV

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I am learning x64 ASM with NASM. I am getting an opcode and operand error. I can't find any really good documentation on it. It is difficult to find any documentation that explains it well enough.

```
; nasm/nasm -f macho64 -o asmtest.o asmtest.asm && ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 asmtest.o -o asmtest && ./asmtest
;

; External
;
    ; none

; Define
;
    %define SYSCALL_WRITE       0x2000004
    %define SYSCALL_EXIT        0x2000001

; Data
;
section .data

    text            db      "Hi.", 0xA
    textlen         equ     $ - text

section .bss

    tmp             resb    1

; Code
;
section .text

    global start

    start:
        mov     rax,    1
        mov     tmp,    rax
        call    write

    write:
        mov     rax,        SYSCALL_WRITE
        mov     rdi,        1
        mov     rsi,        text
        mov     rdx,        textlen
        syscall
        call    exit

    exit:
        mov     rax,        SYSCALL_EXIT
        mov     rdi,        1
        syscall
```

My error I received was

```
asmtest.asm:32: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Comment: Which line is line 32?

Comment: Sorry! It is 'mov     tmp,    rax'

Answer (score 3):

`mov tmp, rax` is illegal because nasm requires square brackets `[]` around memory operands. As such, what you want is `mov [tmp], rax`. This is of course mentioned in the nasm manual, see the section aptly named [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2).

Note however that `rax` is 64 bits, meaning 8 bytes, and you have only reserved 1 byte at `tmp`. In this case that might work, because nothing important seems to be after `tmp` in `.bss`, and page size works in your favor so you probably have space for your extra 7 bytes. Nevertheless you should really reserve as many bytes as you wish to use.

Comment: When I do 'mov [tmp], rax', I get 'asmtest.asm:32: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses'

Comment: Use `mov [rel tmp], rax` to have nasm generate rip-relative encoding for you, or insert at the top of your file `default rel` so it does that for all memory operands automatically.